dynamic Navbar affecting static pages
I have a Next.js 14 application using the new App Router. My RootLayout currently looks like this:
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import { AuthProvider } from "@/context/Auth";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className="flex"
        style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
      >
        <Header />
        <AuthProvider>{children}</AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

The Header component fetches user data dynamically from the server to personalize the navigation bar. This makes the entire app dynamic, including all child pages, some of which were previously static and should remain that way for better performance and SEO.
I'd appreciate any guidance on how to balance these requirements
